# PHP/SQL Multi INSERT INTO dont work

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, insert

I cant insert 2 tabs at once.
It only insert 1 of them (In this example, it inserts the first one)

```
   function addNewUser($username, $password, $email){
      $time = time();
      /* If admin sign up, give admin user level */
      if(strcasecmp($username, ADMIN_NAME) == 0){
         $ulevel = ADMIN_LEVEL;
      }else{
         $ulevel = USER_LEVEL;
      }
    $datumregistrationbla = date("d.m.Y");
      $q = "INSERT INTO ".TBL_USERS." (username, password, email, userlevel, register_date) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', '$ulevel', '$datumregistrationbla')";
      return mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
      $q = "INSERT INTO `post` (`post_id`, `from`, `to`, `betreff`, `text`, `datum`, `active`) VALUES ('', 'Fuchsfeuer', '$username', 'Test', 'Test2', '$datumregistrationbla', '0')";
      return mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you `return` the first `mysql_query` and the rest will not be executed.Try removing it like this.

```
function addNewUser($username, $password, $email){
      $time = time();
      /* If admin sign up, give admin user level */
      if(strcasecmp($username, ADMIN_NAME) == 0){
         $ulevel = ADMIN_LEVEL;
      }else{
         $ulevel = USER_LEVEL;
      }
    $datumregistrationbla = date("d.m.Y");
      $q = "INSERT INTO ".TBL_USERS." (username, password, email, userlevel, register_date) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', '$ulevel', '$datumregistrationbla')";
      mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
      $q = "INSERT INTO `post` (`post_id`, `from`, `to`, `betreff`, `text`, `datum`, `active`) VALUES ('', 'Fuchsfeuer', '$username', 'Test', 'Test2', '$datumregistrationbla', '0')";
      mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
   }
```

Please forget using `mysql_*` because it is deprecated and in php 7 it was already removed. 
Try to use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://hp.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)